# Modify script loaded from page

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say a website was loading this script:

```html
<script src="https://example.com/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Assuming I had access to it, I could modify the script. Though, in this scenario, I don't have access.
Would it be possible to some how "replace" the contents of that script, without changing the URL?

For example, the original script is:

```js
alert("Hello, World!");
```

But my modified version is:

```js
alert("Hello!");
```

However, the URL (to the script) would stay the same.

I know this might sound complicated but, hypothetically, is this possible? At least client-side?

Comment: Scripts are executed synchronously when they are read by the browser. Any code like that in your contrived example will have already been executed and the `alert()` call fired prior to your code (presumably loaded later) has even loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the script (clint only) by using a userscript manager like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=it). 
This is not going to change the loaded script, but you can load your custom script.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. I need to modify a script hosted on an inaccessible web-server, by some how redirecting the URL to a different script - at least client-side. I'm aware of TamperMonkey, though this just injects a script into the web-page (which is not what I'm asking for).

Comment: @Nanoo you could try using TM to edit the src of the script